# Select dates in ranges list

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have table with records, each row contains `DATETIME` column which describes when row was loaded into table. And I have CTE which creates ranges (count is vary) like one below.

```
    first_day_of_month             last_day_of_moth
    -------------------------------------------------------
    2013-12-01 00:00:00.000        2013-12-31 23:59:59.000
    2013-11-01 00:00:00.000        2013-12-31 23:59:59.000
    2013-10-01 00:00:00.000        2013-12-31 23:59:59.000
    2013-09-01 00:00:00.000        2013-12-31 23:59:59.000
    2013-08-01 00:00:00.000        2013-12-31 23:59:59.000
```

**Question:** Now I want to select minimal `DATETIME` value from first table for each range created in CTE. I am absolutely have no idea how to do it. Any ideas/links are appreciated.

For example, it should looks like:

```
2013-12-10
2013-11-20
2013-10-05
2013-09-13
2013-08-06
```

**UPD**: Date or datetime - it is no matter

**UPD2**: I found that I can join my tables using condition like:

```
INNER JOIN source_monthes_dates ON
    (load_timestamp >= first_day_of_month AND load_timestamp <= last_day_of_moth)
```

but actually I do not know how to acquire only first date of period.

Comment: Why are the ranges overlapping?

Comment: @Szymon it is my mistake. I fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this query which uses `ROW_NUMBER()` to get the minimum. `ranges` is the result of your CTE, `table1` is the other table where you have dates.

```
select x.somedate
from
  (select t.somedate,
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY r.first_day_of_month, r.last_day_of_moth ORDER BY t.somedate) rownumber
  from ranges r
  inner join table1 t
  on r.first_day_of_month <= t.somedate and r.last_day_of_moth >= t.somedate) x
where x.rownumber = 1
```

[SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ae8ae/3)

---

If you want to get all the ranges and include only those days that match ranges and display null for others, you can join `ranges` once more:

```
select ranges.first_day_of_month, ranges.last_day_of_moth, x.somedate
from
  ranges
left join
  (select t.somedate, r.first_day_of_month, r.last_day_of_moth,
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY r.first_day_of_month, r.last_day_of_moth ORDER BY t.somedate) rownumber
  from ranges r
  inner join table1 t
  on r.first_day_of_month <= t.somedate and r.last_day_of_moth >= t.somedate) x
on x.first_day_of_month = ranges.first_day_of_month and x.last_day_of_moth = ranges.last_day_of_moth 
where isnull(x.rownumber, 1) = 1
```

[SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ebd12/19)

Comment: Is there way to do the same except keep NULL values in place of absent values? I.e. if nothing found by row_number=1 then place NULL unstead. I tried to play with different JOIN types but have not any luck.

Comment: You can left join ranges table and this query and that should give you what you need. I'll come back to that later.

Comment: Sorry for bothering, another question - is there way to get last load_timestamp for first month (first by row_number)? inner joining inner select with the same one but ordered by load_timestamp DESC not gave me expected result.

Comment: You will need to change the order in `ROW_NUMBER() OVER(...)`. Is that what you did?

Comment: Yes, it is first what I've done. But issue is in following condintion: I'd like to get last date inside month bounds only for the first month, for all other condition `x.rownumber = 1` is absolutely fine. It seens that I need to add anothe `select` insilde `left join` with reverse order of row numbering, but I cannot join it. I prepares code like that: http://pastebin.com/k71RQiYf

Comment: What you can do in this case is to create 2 separate queries (for the first month and the rest) and then union them.